# Creating directory and saving text file in existing directory unless its needs to be created

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a directory from a textbox and also save name from the same textbox input as file name. Tried it several ways but its just keeps shooting out errors unknow. No matter what way i write it maybe i am missing something. I like to know where i am going wrong.
 This is the only way that doesnt show an error till i run it then says unknown. Any help would be great.

```
private void savePictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(@"C:\" + modNameTextBox .ToString() + modNameTextBox + ". txt");
File.Writer(aboutRichTextBox);
File.Close();
```

Comment: Start by using modNameTextBox.Text instead of .ToString(). Same for the RichEditor.

Comment: When using RichTextBox, you can use [RichTextBox.SaveFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4a710b1(v=vs.110).aspx), Also consider using [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that should get you started.

```
string filePath = @"C:\" + modNameTextBox .ToString() + modNameTextBox + ". txt";
string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
if(!Directory.Exists(folder))
{
     Directory.Create(folder);
}
File.WriteAllText(filepath, aboutRichTextBox);
```

Note that you will need to add some Using statements for Path, File, and Directory.
A proper solution will handle the case of a user not typing in a valid directory in the textbox, but that can get a bit complicated (I recommend using SaveFileDialog instead.)

Comment: - Instead of some using statements it's better to say `System.IO`, - instead of aboutRichtextBox, you should say `aboutRichTextBox.Text`, - `Directory.Create` doesn't need to perform check before and it will create All directories and subdirectories in the path :)